# Select2 with tags set to true: Is it possible to always keep the placeholder after selecting the options?

Tags: jquery-select2, placeholder

I want the placeholder to be shown always whether the option is added, selected, or removed. Currently, the placeholder shows after removing the options or after adding the new options. But when the option is selected from the dropdown the placeholder will disappear. This may be the original functionality of the seelct2 plugin. Is there any way to keep the placeholder always visible?

```js
$("select.add-tags").select2({
  tags: true,
  dropdownParent: $(".select-tags"),
  placeholder: "Start typing the tag name..."
});
if ($("select.add-tags").select2("data").length) {
  $("select.add-tags")
    .next()
    .find(".select2-search.select2-search--inline .select2-search__field")
    .attr("placeholder", "Placeholder on default");
  $("select.add-tags")
    .next()
    .find(".select2-search.select2-search--inline .select2-search__field")
    .css("width", "200px");
}
$("select.add-tags").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
  // console.log($(this).val());
  console.log("select2 : select");
  var element = evt.params.data.element;
  var $element = $(element);
  $element.detach();
  $(this).append($element);
  $(this).trigger("change");
  if (
    $(".select2-search.select2-search--inline .select2-search__field").is(
      ":focus"
    )
  ) {
    console.log("tag input fpcused");
    $(".select2-search.select2-search--inline").removeAttr("style");
    $(
      ".select2-search.select2-search--inline .select2-search__field"
    ).removeAttr("style");
    $(".select2-search.select2-search--inline .select2-search__field").attr(
      "placeholder",
      "Placeholder on select"
    );
    $(".select2-search.select2-search--inline .select2-search__field").css(
      "width",
      "200px"
    );
  }
});

$("select.add-tags").on("select2:unselect", function () {
  console.log($(this).val());
  console.log("select2 : unselect");
  if ($("select.add-tags").val().length == 0) {
    $(".select2-search.select2-search--inline .select2-search__field").attr(
      "placeholder",
      "Start typing the tag name..."
    );
    $(".select2-search.select2-search--inline .select2-search__field").css(
      "width",
      "100%"
    );
    $(".select2-search.select2-search--.select2-search__field").css(
      "width",
      "100%"
    );
  } else {
    $(".select2-search.select2-search--inline .select2-search__field").attr(
      "placeholder",
      "Add another tag"
    );
    $(".select2-search.select2-search--inline .select2-search__field").css(
      "width",
      "200px"
    );
    $(".select2-search.select2-search--inline").removeAttr("style");
  }
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2-bootstrap-css/1.4.6/select2-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="container select-tags">
  <select class="add-tags error" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue" selected>Blue</option>
    <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jagruti23/pen/bGggJZR